# Huawei Unlock code site not working - How to get Honor 6X unlock code?

Tags: rooting, huawei, bootloader-lock

All is in the title : How to get Honor 6x unlock code since this url 'https://emui.huawei.com/en/plugin/unlock/index' is dead ?

Comment: Have you tried to contact the Huawei support?

Comment: Related thread link: [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/mate-10/how-to/emui-unlock-site-page-t3779658/). Most of them over there seemed to have solved the issue by mailing Huawei support with their IMEIs requesting for unlock code.